# Can I write from a personal perspective in my bachelor thesis?

Tags: thesis, bachelor

I currently finish my bachelor thesis in computer science. And sometimes I wonder if I write too personal, since my thesis should be an academic piece.

More specific, I wrote a computer program (which has no name at the moment) and I often don't know how to refer to that program and me working on that program.
Can I say something like: "My program consists of two parts ...", or "I implemented a function that does ..."?
Or should I be always completely objective and say "The program of this thesis consists of two parts..." and "The program of this thesis has a function that does ...", which feels a bit counterintuitive.

Comment: This is about writing style, which ELU doesn't do. Theses and style are more on topic on Academia.

Comment: Could you write a couple of example sentences in full? This would give a starting point.

Comment: Give the program a name. It's much easier if you can write "We used an Excel function to do something" than if you have to write something like "We used a function of the spreadsheet software developed by Microsoft" each time.

Comment: It is *your* thesis, so the program has been written by you. So you describe the properties of the program "The program can be used to ...", "The output shown in Figure X demonstrates ..."

Comment: @FedericoPoloni i edited the post so hopefully it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: @Polygnome yes that makes sense. What if I talk about other programs in the same paragraph, then it gets a bit confusing.

Comment: @Timo You would disambiguate in the same way you do it when talking about two programs not written by you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Academic style values clarity and conciseness. Calling it "my program" is entirely appropriate according to these criteria as any alternative is much longer without giving additional clarity. If you want, you can use the plural (our program), but this is a bit old-fashioned.

Comment: From an attribution perspective, using “my” rather than “our” is better as it leaves no doubt as to the author of the said program.